# dotnet core 2.2 webAPI doesn't respond after containerized in Docker

Tags: docker, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am learning Docker.  I created a .net core 2.2 webAPI and am able to interact with it using Postman.  I then created a Dockerfile and added it to a Docker container.  I am not able to interact with the api anymore.  I think I have misconfigured something.  Also, I am developing on an Ubuntu 19.04 machine.

I have looked at several Dockerfiles in .net core projects on github and have read several questions on SO, but have not been able to figure it out.

My docker run command:

```
docker run -d -p 80:5001 blogapi:latest
```

My get request in Postman:

```
https://0.0.0.0:80/api/blog
```

My project file structure looks like this:

```
blog
  |
  --BlogApi
       |
       --BlogApi.csproj
       --Dockerfile
       --Program.cs
       --Startup.cs
       --...
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY . ./
WORKDIR /app/
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out .
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BlogApi.dll"]
```

result of running docker inspect on the running container:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "88c7c5584c3e29423a2ce49deb9e50a52c131621d5cbb994751a645aba797c8f",
        "Created": "2019-06-07T18:49:32.911199534Z",
        "Path": "dotnet",
        "Args": [
            "BlogApi.dll"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 26762,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2019-06-07T18:49:39.970680347Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:b5e50590a06afae8eab09c5b748fdd97a22252a69fef3e8eb9a3916bbe1f8fd8",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/88c7c5584c3e29423a2ce49deb9e50a52c131621d5cbb994751a645aba797c8f/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/88c7c5584c3e29423a2ce49deb9e50a52c131621d5cbb994751a645aba797c8f/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/88c7c5584c3e29423a2ce49deb9e50a52c131621d5cbb994751a645aba797c8f/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/88c7c5584c3e29423a2ce49deb9e50a52c131621d5cbb994751a645aba797c8f/88c7c5584c3e29423a2ce49deb9e50a52c131621d5cbb994751a645aba797c8f-json.log",
        "Name": "/peaceful_buck",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "5001/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "shareable",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9993c5bb1be9533897834e03038a2247ac52f0b2043414807e437d075e5448e6-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b53ea9ebd00b2c4cdc83d5df8905241dbd1b2413abbe38161336543e04ab7b32/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/eeac3efbd1b7e13370ee7b640173a07e1b375969dcd75df142409d5c3653688f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7d24ebd98305848e3a3f3494d327826b27fc5cc116995df2720aa3754b37579f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/dbe73936117865157ca2d89f86909bf2ce32443a48ca368dcbb3ef934fbee775/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/13f3a01d82b32c692d8b533cebc22aedaf7691e8c4bc3a2a6d91bf028289a605/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b9554cb92ce0399f6964958300ac2af95cfec4eac08acc0ed01fa8fe26d1def1/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9993c5bb1be9533897834e03038a2247ac52f0b2043414807e437d075e5448e6/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9993c5bb1be9533897834e03038a2247ac52f0b2043414807e437d075e5448e6/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9993c5bb1be9533897834e03038a2247ac52f0b2043414807e437d075e5448e6/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "88c7c5584c3e",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "5001/tcp": {},
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80",
                "DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true",
                "ASPNETCORE_VERSION=2.2.5"
            ],
            "Cmd": null,
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "blogapi:latest",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/app",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "dotnet",
                "BlogApi.dll"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "172dbe50c926349277a2ae67e09639d2e3296625dbec218e51a7526066e78b03",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "5001/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ],
                "80/tcp": null
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/172dbe50c926",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "4e830cf57d2e4534df061a56cf09dd88c10771345cd5e0212612ea8073f0d537",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "57c61c9decd1fbc78a15bc72207a406f767bc6516299a6e5ad33b439ae655520",
                    "EndpointID": "4e830cf57d2e4534df061a56cf09dd88c10771345cd5e0212612ea8073f0d537",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Postman is returning "Could not get any response"

Comment: What if you GET `https://localhost:80/api/blog`?

Comment: FWIW, you're also confusing ports and protocols a little. If you're using SSL in your project, I'd map the docker port to 443 or something other than 80, as 80 is implicitly non-SSL.

Comment: OK, you may be onto something here.  without docker, the webAPI is published to port 5001 for https and 5000 for http.  I have tried http and https, but now I'm wondering if I should have mapped to port 5000 instead of 5001 since I'm not using ssl with docker.

Comment: https://localhost:80/api/blog returns no response

Comment: I ran docker again like this: docker run -d -p 80:5000 blogapi:latest and still get no response on either http or https and using both localhost and 0.0.0.0

Comment: I also tried running docker mapping port 443:5000 and another time to 443:5001 and still get no response.

Comment: What's the output from `docker run -it -p 443:5001 blogapi:latest
`

Comment: response is:  warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {11926e17-9de6-44ce-ad27-8639e984af98} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: http://[::]:80
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is not listening on the ports you're mapping. `5000` and `5001` are common dev defaults for ASP.net Core, but your project is currently just running on port 80 with no SSL. So, you should be able to run it like:

```sh
docker run -d -p 8080:80 blogapi:latest
```

And reach it at `http://localhost:8080/api/blog`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  According to a post on the docker forums here: https://forums.docker.com/t/unable-to-launch-the-net-core-website-in-docker/48129  you need to run docker inspect [containerid] and find the ip address of the container.  When I ran docker inspect I found the following:

```
"Networks": {
    "bridge": {
        "IPAMConfig": null,
        "Links": null,
        "Aliases": null,
        "NetworkID": "57c61c9decd1fbc78a15bc72207a406f767bc6516299a6e5ad33b439ae655520",
        "EndpointID": "36a50f4be28ced0f8751222df789dabf8f7bf9dc4934b8c075c25fc775a74097",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
        "DriverOpts": null
    }
}
```

I was then able to interact with the api at this address:

```
http://172.17.0.2/api/blog
```

Postman response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "First Post",
        "body": null,
        "timeStamp": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
    }
]
```